# Return of uint QDir::count () const in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4

Suppose i have  one folder and inside that another two files are there .

But when i am using uint QDir::count () const, it gives me 4 instead of 2 . the extra 2 is for "." and ".." .i dont understand what is this "." and ".."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"." is the current folder, and ".." is the parent folder.  It's more a Linux thing, than a Windows thing.  You can ignore them if you're just counting files in a folder.

Comment: Suppose the directory structure is as follows a->b,c and A->a then in this case if i apply the above function , then "." represents a since it holds b and c , whereas ".." represents A which holds a . Am i right ????